# How to read input from S3 in a Spark Streaming EC2 cluster application

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm trying to make my Spark Streaming application reading his input from a S3 directory but I keep getting this exception after launching it with spark-submit script:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Credentials.initialize(S3Credentials.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy6.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.initialize(NativeS3FileSystem.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.checkpoint(StreamingContext.scala:195)
    at MainClass$.main(MainClass.scala:1190)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I'm setting those variables through this block of code as suggested here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html (bottom of the page):

```
val ssc = new org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext(
  conf,
  Seconds(60))
ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId",args(2))
ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey",args(3))
```

args(2) and args(3) are my AWS Access Key ID and Secrete Access Key of course.

Why it keeps saying they are not set?

EDIT: I tried also this way but I get the same exception:

```
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("s3n://"+ args(2) +":"+ args(3) + "@<mybucket>/path/")
```

Comment: Are you avoiding IAM roles for a reason?  And wanting to use access/secret keys instead?

Comment: Not really, I was just following the instructions on the documentation (back then). Now with all new updates its probably an outdated question for most use cases.

Comment: Have you tried to access the files using s3a://....?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Odd. Try also doing a `.set` on the `sparkContext`. Try also exporting env variables before you start the application:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your access>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<your secret>
```

^^this is how we do it.

UPDATE: According to @tribbloid the above broke in 1.3.0, now you have to faff around for ages and ages with hdfs-site.xml, or your can do (and this works in a spark-shell):

```
val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration;
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", myAccessKey)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", mySecretKey)
```

Comment: You mean exporting them from the shell in the master and all slaves before using spark-submit? Or doing it inside the application with sys.env?

Comment: In the shell before you execute the application.  Just in that shell, no need to execute it in any other shell other than the shell you execute the application.

Comment: Exporting env variables before starting the application worked! 
Thank you!

Comment: Note: Setting `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` or `fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId` in the SparkConf().set(...) didn't do it. Setting `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` in the Env or setting it in `spark-env.sh` did work. Sadly the non-working cases *should work*.

Comment: This no longer works after Spark 1.3. Now if you want to set up it statically. You have to add hdfs-site.xml into Spark's conf directory. There is no way to set it in commandline. I don't know the point of this design but it just happened

Comment: what would be the option if you had to juggle different keys at same time but didn't want to hardcode them in code using `hadoopConf`?

Answer (score 22):

The following configuration works for me, make sure you also set "fs.s3.impl":

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local")      
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val hadoopConf=sc.hadoopConfiguration;
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId",myAccessKey)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey",mySecretKey)
```

Comment: Much cleaner than dumping secrets into the Env.

Comment: It appears that in Python the hadoopConfiguration attribute is not available. Any ideas of a workaround?

Comment: In pyspark it's `hadoopConf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()`

Comment: @JosephLust cleaner is to not set these at all but to use IAM roles.  You are forcing something to manage and protect these secrets when it isn't required.

Comment: @JaysonMinard good point. We don't use EC2 Roles on our Spark cluster due to multi-tenancy of jobs, where specific jobs are restricted to specific buckets. Our distributed configuration service takes care of providing the proper secrets to the proper job.

Answer (score 3):

On AWS EMR the above suggestions did not work. Instead I updated the following properties in the conf/core-site.xml:

fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey with your S3 credentials.

Comment: "Above" doesn't mean anything when the order of answers can change at any time.  For EMR the answer from @ChristopherB looks correct.

Answer (score 3):

For those using EMR, use the Spark build as described at https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/spark and just reference S3 with the s3:// URI. No need to set S3 implementation or additional configuration as credentials are set by IAM or role.

Comment: IAM role is recommended over specifying keys in any other way.

Comment: From the current 4.x EMR admin guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles.html

Comment: I have all S3 permissions in place for the IAM that is being used to create spark cluster. But still I am facing this error.

Comment: @nishant is this with EMR?  If so what EMR version? And on EMR don't set the AWS keys within the Spark app.

Comment: @ChristopherB There was a problem with the role I defined. I fixed it and now its working.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to put the credentials more securely in a config file on one of my encrypted partitions.  So I did `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=~/Private/.aws/hadoop_conf` before running my spark application, and put a file in that directory (encrypted via `ecryptfs`) called `core-site.xml` containing the credentials like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
  <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
  <value>my_aws_access_key_id_here</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
  <value>my_aws_secret_access_key_here</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

`HADOOP_CONF_DIR` can also be set in `conf/spark-env.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Latest EMR releases (tested on 4.6.0) require the following configuration:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", myAccessKey)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", mySecretKey)
```

Although in most cases out of the box config should work - this is if you have different S3 credentials from the ones you launched the cluster with.

Answer (score 1):

In java, the following are the lines of code. You have to add AWS creds in SparkContext only and not SparkSession.

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_KEY);
sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me in 1.4.1 shell:

```
val conf = sc.getConf
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", <your access key>)
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", <your secret key>)
SparkHadoopUtil.get.conf.addResource(SparkHadoopUtil.get.newConfiguration(conf))
...
sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://...")
```

Comment: This is technically the same as the answer from  @harel, you just set from higher up in the configuration tree instead of going to the Hadoop configuration first.  But it is the same.

Comment: Not the same for spark shell - you already have sc and sqlContext in the shell, @harel's answer creates a new conf and new sc.

Answer (score 0):

Augmenting @nealmcb's answer, the most straightforward way to do this is to define

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

in `conf/spark-env.sh` or export that env variable in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

That will work as long as you can access s3 through hadoop.  For instance, if you can run

```
hadoop fs -ls s3n://path/
```

then hadoop can see the s3 path.

If hadoop can't see the path, follow the advice of contained in [How can I access S3/S3n from a local Hadoop 2.6 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029134/how-can-i-access-s3-s3n-from-a-local-hadoop-2-6-installation)