# Spark Streaming checkpoint to amazon s3

Tags: spark-streaming

I am trying to checkpoint the rdd to non-hdfs system. From [DSE document](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaCFS.html) it seems that it is not possible to use cassandra file system. So I am planning to use amazon s3 . But I am not able to find any good example to use the AWS.

**Questions**

- How do I use Amazon S3 as checkpoint directory ?Is it just enough to call
   ssc.checkpoint(amazons3url) ?
- Is it possible to have any other reliable data storage other than hadoop file system for checkpoint ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048729/how-to-read-input-from-s3-in-a-spark-streaming-ec2-cluster-application)

Solution 1:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your access>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<your secret>
ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)
```

Set the checkpoint directory as S3 URL - 
`s3n://spark-streaming/checkpoint`

And then launch your spark application using spark submit.
This works in `spark 1.4.2`

solution 2:

```
  val hadoopConf: Configuration = new Configuration()
  hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
  hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "id-1")
  hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "secret-key")

  StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkPointDir, () => {
        createStreamingContext(checkPointDir, config)
      }, hadoopConf)
```

Answer (score 3):

To Checkpoint to S3, you can pass the following notation to [StreamingContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext) `def checkpoint(directory: String): Unit` method

```
s3n://<aws-access-key>:<aws-secret-key>@<s3-bucket>/<prefix ...>
```

Another reliable file system not listed in the [Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) for checkpointing, is [Taychyon](http://tachyon-project.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The secret key usually has a slash in it. So this is not working.