# Access environment variables from Spark Worker

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have an application that requires accessing DynamoDB tables. Each worker establishes a connection with the database on its own.

I have added both `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to both master's and workers `spark-env.sh` file. I have also run the file using `sh` to make sure the variables are exported.

When the code runs, I always get the error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:774)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:800)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:695)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:447)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:409)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:358)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2051)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2021)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1299)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBDelegate.describeTable(DynamoDBDelegate.java:635)
    ... 27 more
```

It seems that the AWS SDK has failed to load the credentials even though they're exported. What type of solution should I try?

Comment: Can you try setting it explicitly in the code ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475931/spark-streaming-checkpoint-to-amazon-s3

Comment: @Knight71 , I could but isn't that insecure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setExecutorEnv` method on the `SparkConf`. E.g

```
  /**
   * Set an environment variable to be used when launching executors for this application.
   * These variables are stored as properties of the form spark.executorEnv.VAR_NAME
   * (for example spark.executorEnv.PATH) but this method makes them easier to set.
   */
  def setExecutorEnv(variable: String, value: String): SparkConf = {
    set("spark.executorEnv." + variable, value)
  }
```

Also

```
  /**
   * Set multiple environment variables to be used when launching executors.
   * These variables are stored as properties of the form spark.executorEnv.VAR_NAME
   * (for example spark.executorEnv.PATH) but this method makes them easier to set.
   */
  def setExecutorEnv(variables: Seq[(String, String)]): SparkConf = {
    for ((k, v) <- variables) {
      setExecutorEnv(k, v)
    }
    this
  }
```

You might consider other options such as setting java System properties: the `SparkConf` will automatically pick them up.

Comment: and read that value in executors like below                                                  ::::::    val property_value=System.getEnv("property_key")